# SQL Relations on tables in different Schemes

Tags: sql-server

I am designing an ER Model and I decided to use schemes to separate tables with the same names for different departments.

Now i want to create general purpose tables that hold data that will use the default scheme .dbo

My doubt is if it's possible for tables in different schemes have foreign keys to a .dbo one and rely on it instead of duplicating it on every scheme

I tried to search about it but ironically I get no results on google about relations on tables in different schemes

Comment: You could just be over complicating the matter. Why don't you just have one table with a `DepartmentId` value to allow you to use the same table for both departments. It would likely make you life and code a lot simpler. What's the justification for splitting by schema?

Comment: Because outside the database feeds an ASP.NET Core Application which is split by Areas, Production, Administration, Robotics.   Each area can use the same tables or can have tables which are basically the same but are independent. It's basically many applications into one, hence why use schemes rather than multiple databases. Plus tables with the same names have different columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your difficulty is searching for "schemes" instead of `SCHEMA`?

There is no problem creating foreign keys between tables in different schema, at least on SQL Server 2017...

```sql
if object_id(N'guest.Department') is not null
    drop table guest.Department;
if object_id(N'dbo.Department') is not null
    drop table dbo.Department;
go
create table dbo.Department (
    DepartmentID int not null identity(1,1),
    Department nvarchar(50) not null,
    constraint PK_dbo_Department
        primary key nonclustered (DepartmentID)
);
create table guest.Department (
    DepartmentID int not null,
    SomethingElse bit not null,
    constraint ixU_guest_Department_DepartmentID
        unique nonclustered (DepartmentID),
    constraint FK_guest_Department_DepartmentID_dbo_Department
        foreign key (DepartmentID)
        references dbo.Department (DepartmentID)
);
go
insert dbo.Department (Department) values ('Human Resources');
insert guest.Department (DepartmentID, SomethingElse) values (1, 1); --Succeeds
insert guest.Department (DepartmentID, SomethingElse) values (42, 1); --Fails due to FK
go
select * from dbo.Department;
select * from guest.Department;
go
```

Comment: I see, my bad, i'm not english and i kept saying "schemes". Thanks for confirming tho

Comment: @Jackal No problem at all. Glad to help. Good luck with your project, sounds like it could get hairy.